# CGContextMoveToPoint moves to wrong position

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm new to core graphics and I'm struggling with a simple task of putting a sweeping circle inside a square. The outcome I got looks like this:

[image]

The circle won't appear at the center of the square, and the size of the circle appears much smaller than I specified.

Below is my `drawRect` method for drawing the circle. I have put the printed-out variable values while debugging in the comments for your convenience. I also printed out the value passed to `initWithFrame`: frame=(0 0; 256 256). The frame is the orange square you see in the picture.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat midX = CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds); // bounds = (0 0; 256 256); midX = 128
CGFloat midY = CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds); // midY = 128
CGFloat radius = midY - 4; // radius = 124

// Outer grey pie
[endColor setFill];
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, midX, midY); // move to center
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(midX - radius, midY - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2)); // adds a circle of radius = square_side_length - 4
CGContextFillPath(context); // fill the circle above with grey

// Show the clock
NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
CGFloat mod =  fmod(seconds, self.period);
CGFloat percent = mod / self.period;

[fillColor setFill]; 
CGFloat start = -M_PI_2;
CGFloat end = 2 * M_PI;
CGFloat sweep = end * percent + start;
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, midX, midY);
CGContextAddArc(context, midX, midY, radius, start, sweep, 0); // radius = square_side_length - 24
CGContextFillPath(context);

// Innermost white pie
radius -= 50; // radius = square_side_length - 54
[bgColor setFill]; // white
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, midX, midY);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(midX - radius, midY - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2));
CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

And below is the code that adds the clock to its superview:

```
clock = [[ProgressClock alloc] initWithFrame:self.clockHolder.bounds // bounds=[0 0; 256 256]
                                     period:[TOTPGenerator defaultPeriod]
                                     bgColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                 strokeColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.2]
                                   fillColor:[UIColor blueColor]
                                    endColor:[UIColor grayColor]
                                       shade:NO];
[self.clockHolder addSubview:clock];
```

Can anyone spot the mistake I made? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the drawing code. I just copy and pasted it into an empty project and I'm getting this: https://infinit.io/_/3keDU7K. I think it's a problem with your view's frame.

Comment: @originaluser2 thanks very much for trying that out for me. So I have a container (a square), that has frame=(32 63; 256, 256) and bounds=(0 0; 256 256). The container contains a clock holder (the orange square in the post) which has the exact dimension and position as the container itself, with frame=(0 0; 256 256) and bounds=(0 0; 256 256). This makes sense as container is the superview of clock holder, so the frame of the clock holder originates at (0, 0). Since the drawing in drawRect are all done in user space, I thought it didn't matter where the container is. Am I wrong?

Comment: @originaluser2 Also I just added the code that presents the clock to the end of this post, in case the issue was within that part. The clockHolder itself was positioned in storyboard so I can't find a way to show that to you.

Comment: yes, you are correct about the coordinates. It doesn't matter where your view is positioned - Core Graphics drawing is done within the view's bounds, so that's not the problem. Is the orange background in your `clock` or your `clockHolder`?

Comment: @originaluser2 the orange background belongs to clockHolder. clockHolder is the canvas on which I am drawing the clock.

Comment: do you change the clockHolder's frame after adding the the clock? Or are there constraints on it that could potentially change its frame after you add the clock?

Comment: @originaluser2 your last comment was extremely helpful (sequence of events) and I made it work by moving the clock presenting logic from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear` and it shows up perfectly! I am guessing the initialization in storyboard and the clock animation got into some sort of conflicts. Thanks so much for the clue! :D

Comment: no worries! Auto-layout can be really annoying sometimes, which is why I actually never use storyboards in any of my projects :P Glad you found a solution though!

Comment: What is the `contentMode` of your clock view?

Comment: @robmayoff it's `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to @originaluser2's comment, I have fixed this issue simply by moving the clock presenting logic from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear` and the clock showed up perfectly. There was nothing wrong with the drawing code I posted; however the auto-layout initialization and the animation of my clock happened in a sequence that gave my drawing canvas a wrong frame. By putting the drawing logic in `viewDidAppear`, we are guaranteed that all the auto-layout setup has been completed, thus frames are fixed, before continue onto drawing the circle.